# if ( (my_fgets(line, max, fp)) == NULL) warning :comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]

Tags: c

this is my code:

`my_fgets.c`

```
#include<stdio.h>

char *my_fgets(char *s,int maxlen,FILE *fp)
{
    register int c;
    register char *cs;

    cs = s;
    while(--maxlen >0 && (c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
        if((*cs++ = c) == '\n')
            break;
    *cs = '\0';
    return (c == EOF && cs == s)? NULL: cs;
}
```

`my_getline.c`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

/* getline : read a line, return lenght */ 
int my_getline(char *line, int max,FILE *fp)
{
    if ( (my_fgets(line, max, fp)) == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
        return strlen(line);
}
```

When I compiled the my_getline.c , I got a warning.

```
[root@server0 fgets]# gcc -c my_getline.c
my_getline.c: In function ‘my_getline’:
my_getline.c:7:36: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled 
by default]
     if ( (my_fgets(line, max, fp)) == NULL)
                                    ^
```

I don't know where this program have errors. Could you tell me?
**Thank you!**

Comment: Since you don’t declare the function signature for `my_gets` in-line or in a header the compiler assumes it returns `int`

Comment: Advanced: Code also has a subtle difference between `fgets()` and `my_fgets()`. When `EOF` is returned and to was due an error (not end-of-file), the return value should be `NULL;` as in `return (c == EOF && (cs == s || !feof(fp))? NULL: cs;`.  Note: file input errors are rare.

Comment: @ClancyZeng, Another advanced corner issue: Start with `if (maxlen <= 0) return NULL;` to handle pathological, but legal, input.  Else `*cs = '\0';` is a problem.

Comment: You are right.I never thought that point.Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the function in either a heade file or inline in `my_getline.c`:

```
char *my_fgets(char *s,int maxlen,FILE *fp);
```

Is the declaration. Either put that before your `my_getline` function or in `my_fgets.h` (with include guards) and #include that header in both your `.c` files.

Without it the compiler assumes any function it sees without a declaration returns `int`